# median of five points python

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, median

My data frame (`df`) has a list of numbers (total 1773) and I am trying to find a median for five numbers (e.g. the `median of 3rd number = median (1st,2nd,3rd,4th,5th)`)

```
num
10
20
15
34
...
...
...

def median(a, b, c,d,e):
    I=[a,b,c,d,e]
    return I[2]



num_median = [num[0]]

for i in range(1, len(num)):
    num_median = median(num[i - 1], num[i-2], num[i],num[i+1],num[i+2])

df['num_median']=num_median


IndexError: index 1773 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1773
```

Where did it go wrong and Is there any other method to compute the median?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example which will help:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
print('Length={}'.format(len(a)))
print(a(4))
```

You are trying the same thing. The actual index of an element is one lower than the place it is. Keep in mind your exception shows you *exactly* where your problem is.

You need to modify:

```
for i in range(1, len(num) - 2):
    num_median = median(num[i - 1], num[i-2], num[i],num[i+1],num[i+2])
```

So that your last index check will not be too large. Otherwise, when you are at the end of your array (index = 1773) you will be trying to access an index which doesn't exist (1773 + 2).